# Does Poco c++ support for oaep with sha 256 mgf1 padding?

Tags: c++, poco

I have a quick query..
I have been looking into for crypto algorithms supported in poco cpp library.

I see various padding modes in the latest poco 1.12, but i couldn't see whether it supports rsa with oaep with sha256 and mgf1 padding.
Is it supportted in poco??

I have seen latest poco versions.